# ¿Cómo quitar los decimales (,00) de una lista de System.Decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, .net, entity-framework

Tengo el siguiente método

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var zsp = db.Zsp.Include(z => z.Zsptypes).ToList();


        return View(zsp);
    }
```

Que me devuelve la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para que no se visualizen los ultimos ,00?? Mi modelo es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Andromeda, recuerda que siempre es preferible pegar el código antes que insertar una imagen sobre el mismo, en el caso del registro podria ser, pero no para el código :)

Comment: Cual es el tipo de dato de `.CB`, `.UB`, `.State` y `.Regla` ?

Comment: numeric(18,0) en sql

Comment: Me refería a la clase de C#

Comment: Son decimal,ejemplo :     [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
                                        public decimal Regla { get; set; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que noto es que el mismo modelo de EF es el que usas para la view de mvc, cuando deberías crear una clase `ViewModel` diferente para la vista:

```
public ZspViewModel{
   public string Nombre {get;set;}
   public string State {get;set;}
   //resto propiedades
}
```

entonces crearías el linq así:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var zsp = db.Zsp.Include(z => z.Zsptypes)
                .Select(x=> new ZspViewModel(){
                    Nombre = x.Nombre,
                    Stado = x.Stado.ToString("N0")
                    //resto propiedades
                });
    return View(zsp);
}
```

Al convertir de un tipo a otro, puede aplicar el formato para quitar los decimales.

La clase `ViewModel` la debes crear en la carpeta Model del asp.net mvc

---

Otra tecnica podria usa el [DisplayFormatAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

En este caso tambien debes crear una clase ViewModel, pero no aplcia conversion directa sino que lo haces mediente atributo

```
public ZspViewModel{
   public string Nombre {get;set;}

   [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:N}")]
   public decimal State {get;set;}
   //resto propiedades
}
```

En este caso el linq no usarias el ToString() sino que asignas directo el valor de uan clase a otro.
En estos casos se recomiendo tambien usar [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: usualmente en Stack Overflow y demás sitios de Stack Exchange, se motiva a los usuarios para que generen **una repuesta en lugar de varias entradas en una misma pregunta**, por lo que le sugiero actualizar una de las respuestas publicadas en el sitio para mantener una respuesta por usuario.

Comment: Lo separe en dos respuestas porque son tecnicas distintas, entonces quien realiza la pregunta puede evaluar una de ellas y si le resulta util marcala como correcta. Al separarla le doy la posibilidad de seleccionar cual aplica para resolver el problema, si convertir aplicando formato o simplemente convertir y usar atributos. No seria correcto segun este planteo separar en dos respuestas?

Comment: he leído respuestas en otros sitios de Stack Exchange en donde un usuario formula en diferentes entradas, sus respuestas / alternativas, pero al ser motivados por comentarios de los moderadores para generar **en una entrada, las diferentes opciones que pueda aplicar para responder a la pregunta**, se genera en una sola entrada por usuario, las opciones que puedan aplicar apara responder a la pregunta del OP. Sin embargo, no debe considerarse como algo _que vaya en contra_ de las normas de publicación de preguntas / respuestas. Esa decisión puede ser analizada por los moderadores del sitio.

Comment: Aplicando el DisplayFormat al mi modelo existente funciono perfecto.Gracias

Answer (score 0):

En la vista o modelo puedes llamar al método `.ToString("0")` sobre tus campos numéricos.

Esto mostrará el número redondeado a 0 decimales

Si necesitas más decimales puedes usar la sintaxis:

`.ToString("N0")`

N**0**, N**1**, N**2** o N**n** donde n es el número de decimales que necesitas